# sails sequelize get camelcase attribute in code but snake_case in database

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js

I want to use camelcase in my code or while retrieving the data, but while storing into the database it should store as snake_case.

To achieve that I'm writing the field and name in every model which is painful

currently, I'm doing:

```
  attributes: {
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field:'first_name'
    },
    lastName:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
      field:'last_name'
    }
 }
```

> Is their any easy method for which I achive that?
>
> I did underscore=true in model definition but while retrieving the data I'm getting in underscore.

I'm using MySQL database

Thanks.